# MySQl TinyInt(1) equivalent in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, types, integer

What is the equivalent of MySQL's `TinyInt(1)` in Oracle? I have to create datatype for it in Oracle table

Comment: Without knowing much about MySQL - if I understand the documentation correctly, `tinyint` can be signed or unsigned. Is there a default, so if you simply say `tinyint` it means signed (or perhaps unsigned)? Otherwise, `tinyint` without specifying signed or unsigned isn't even a well-defined data type. So - please clarify (for those of us, like myself, who don't know MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you'd use `NUMBER(1)`.

Comment: I don't know MySQL, but if I am reading it correctly, tinyint(1) can hold one-byte integer values (signed or unsigned). If so, 123 is a valid tinyint(1) value, which may be stored in MySQL. If in Oracle they declare number(1), they will be unable to store the same value in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want: `number(1, 0)`.

This lets you store an integer number between `-9` and `9`.

Note that is *not* equivalent to MySQL `TINYINT(1)`. This datatype can store values between `-128` and `127` (when signed), or `0` and `255`. The `1` in the definition of the datatype is not significant in terms of value range - it merely comes into play when displaying the data in some clients (this is somehow counter-intuitive, and is now planned for deprecation in a future release of MySQL).

Comment: I don't know MySQL, but if I am reading it correctly, tinyint(n) can hold one-byte integer values (signed or unsigned). If so, 123 is a valid tinyint(1) value, which may be stored in MySQL. If in Oracle they declare number(1,0), they will be unable to store the same value in Oracle.

Comment: @mathguy: yes, that's exactly what I am poinpointing in the answer. I suppose, however, that what the OP wants is to store one digit only. Many MySQL users think that the number in `TINYINT(1)` represents the number precision (as in most other SQL dialects).

Comment: that's correct @GMB i want to insert 1 or 0 inside oracle ..